# mac following brew install python warning thrown unstable state

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

1. Pundits warn against installing python in a mac usr/bin/Frameworks area.
2. Python self-installers write to Framework by default.
3. pundits advise using brew install of python to avoid the above.
4. Brew install python however, results in unstable state
5. Idle reports tclsh mismatch.
6. Pundits advise active state installer of correct tclsh.  These are high-level python cognoscenti, and real pundits, lilies amidst the thorns.
7. Active-state installs to Frameworks (can you imagine?).
8. The said installer allows no other installation directory.
9. Brew installed python fails to see the active-state tclsh.

However, if one of you admonitory pundits could help me with a logical, non-idiomatic description of a process that will associate the appropriate "tclsh" in usr/bin with python3 in usr/local/bin, I would be ecstatic.

Answer (score 0):

Homebrew's Python build will only attempt to recognize brewed or system Tcl/Tk. To build against Homebrew's Tcl/Tk (and install it first if necessary), install Python with `brew install python3 --with-tcl-tk`.